# I have written a Case structure in excel that I want to override for some rows

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I have written a case structure (3,4,5,6) that fills in the proper columns. I never expected that I would need to be able to override the case for some rows. Now I need to be able to override a whole row (Column 3,4,5,6). I am not that well versed in this so any help or even a direction to go in would be useful.

I designed this to tally up values of objects in an estate between 4 people. Whoever gets the object still owes the other three their 25% of it. It is working good. But now there are some objects that I am physically splitting between all 4 people evenly. I tried to override the numbers but it continues to follow the cases.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back
    Dim RowNumber As Integer

    Select Case Target.Column

        Case "3"        
            RowNumber = Target.Cells.Row

            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 6).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25

            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value = -(Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.75)
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Font.Color = vbRed

        Case "4"

            RowNumber = Target.Cells.Row        

            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 6).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value = -(Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.75)
           Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Font.Color = vbRed

        Case "5"

            RowNumber = Target.Cells.Row           
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 6).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
            Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Value = -(Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.75)
           Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Font.Color = vbRed
          ' MsgBox "test of recalculate " & Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value

            ... Etc.
```

Comment: Add an `IF` statement? Which you could do before right after `RowNumber = Target.Cells.Row` (which, BTW, should be before the `Select Case` since you do it all the time)

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize a flag in another column to mark rows you want to be able to override manually and then enclose the `Select-Case` (I'm assuming in a `Worksheet_Change` event) in an `If` statement.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back
    Dim RowNumber As Long

    RowNumber = Target.Row

    If Me.Cells(RowNumber, 7) <> "O" Then '<-make column 7 your helper column where you can use letter "O" to flag rows for Override

        Select Case Target.Column

            Case "3"
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 6).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value = -(Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.75)
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
            Case "4"
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 6).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value = -(Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.75)
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Font.Color = vbRed
            Case "5"
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 3).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 4).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 6).Value = Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.25
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Value = -(Me.Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value * 0.75)
                Me.Cells(RowNumber, 5).Font.Color = vbRed

            'etc...for subsequent cases

        End Select

    End If
    'Application.EnableEvents = True
'Exit Sub
'ErrorHandler:
'Error Handling to turn back on Application.EnableEvents
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

I'm assuming you already have an error handler to turn back on `Application.EnableEvents` based on your comments in your code code, so I've just added them as pseudo-code comments in my example.

Comment: Thank you. cybernetic.nomad and Tate Garringer.  I think I will be able to fix this up now.